# Creating a php function to return mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to create a function, that will return a mysql query, which i can then loop through and handle the results, but it doesnt seem to be working. I might not even be doing this the right way.

```
function GetAccounts($username){
require("dbconn.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = '$username' ") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
return "$result";
}

$result = GetAccounts($username);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
$theusername = $row['theusername'];
$thepassword = $row['thepassword'];
echo $theusername;
}
```

The error i recieve is

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

I tried loading all of the above into the function, but could only get it to return a single result each time. Since ill need to handle each result, i "think" the above way is how i want to do it, but let me know if there is a better way, or what im doing wrong.

When i echo the function with the username, i get the following;

```
Resource id #5
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove double quotes around the link variable `$result`.

```
function GetAccounts($username){
  require("dbconn.php");
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = '$username' ") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
  return $result;
 }
```

Comment: It worked great, thanks. What was happening there exactly? Why did quoting the result variable mess it up?

Comment: See Tom's answer below.  Because using double quotes means $result was cast to a string.

Answer (score 11):

Putting `$result` within double quotes means it will be cast to a string, and is then no longer of type 'resource'. Try instead:

```
return $result;
```