# SQL result doesn't work when reassigned

Tags: php, mysql

The code:

```
  $msr = db_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
  if (db_num_rows($msr) == 0)
      return null;
```

When

```
function db_query($query) { return mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . " when querying: $query"); }
function db_num_rows($queres) { return mysql_num_rows($queres) or die(mysql_error()); }
```

Shows error: `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

When I replace "db_" with "mysql_" everything works perfectly.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The errors looks odd - are you sure you copy-pasted it correctly? You seem to be missing the initial `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Creating a php function to return mysql results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292210/creating-a-php-function-to-return-mysql-results)" here on SO.

```
function db_query($query) { 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." when querying: $query"); 
  return $result;
}

// etc
```

Apart from that, you should *absolutely not* do

```
$msr = db_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
```

for security reasons. This is wide open for SQL injection attacks, see [XKCD 327](http://xkcd.com/327/). Use parametrized SQL statements instead.

Comment: Additionally, in every function that returns anything useful, one must assign result to something before returning;

Comment: Well, not necessarily. In this case there is an `or die()` statement that prevents execution flow from ever reaching the `return` in case of an error.